# PLSQL order by numerical order

Tags: plsql

I have a query that returns a column (NUMBER) I would like to use ORDER BY so the results will be in numerical order for example: 1,2,3,4,5 
and not: 1,10,12,3,4,5.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please include the query mentioned to your question. The one that returns the NUMBER column.

Comment: So whats the issue. Use `Order by Column asc`

Comment: I did, does not work

Comment: ORDER BY does respect numbers and provides numeric sorting. Your example seems to be ordering strings. Please post more details so we can see where the break is.

Answer (score 1):

If the column has a numeric type, what you want is the default behavior.
If it has another type but is meant to have contents parsable as integers, reconsider your design. Then reconsider it again. Then reconsider it a third time. If after all you really want a textual column ordered as numbers, you can

```
ORDER BY CAST(column AS NUMBER)
```

but beware that it will be slow and you might receive errors if the column values do not parse as numbers...

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly the below one I tried from my machine Oracle 11gr2 and its working. If its not working in your case then issue is somewhere else.

```
SQL> create table tbb(a number);
/

SQL> select * from tbb;

         A
----------
         1
         2
         4
         6
         3
         7

6 rows selected.

SQL> select * from tbb order by a;

         A
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         6
         7

6 rows selected.

SQL> drop table tbb;

Table dropped.
```